# Show two div in same line in same horizontal line from top

Tags: html, css

Here is my code

```css
.floating-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

.after-box {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h2>The New Way - using inline-block</h2>

<div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
<div class="floating-box">
  <pre>
    testing
    testing
    testing
    testing
    testing
    testing
    testing
    </div>
    <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
    <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
    <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
    <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
    <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
    <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
    
    <div class="after-box">Another box, after the floating boxes...</div>
```

I want to have a view like this

[image]

is there any way to do this? if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `vertical-align: top;` property in `.floating-box` class in css. 
New CSS will be

```
.floating-box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is your friend. I don't know how flexible or fluid you wanted this to be, but it should be close enough.

Pay particular attention to the `calc()` function. It's taking care of the border thickness and margins you have set.

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: calc(33% - 6px - 20px);
  max-width: calc(33% - 6px - 20px);
}

.floating-box {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

.after-box {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h2>The New Way - using inline-block</h2>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
  <div class="floating-box">
    <pre>
testing
testing
testing
testing
testing
testing
testing
</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
<div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>


</div>

<div class="after-box">Another box, after the floating boxes...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-table` and `vertical-align:top` for `.floating-box` class.
So, the new CSS will be-

```
.floating-box {
  display: inline-table;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also do it by `float: left` alone instead of `display:inline-table` and `vertical-align:top` . But for this, you need to specify a height(say, `height: 150px`) which would result in a lot of blank spaces,