# Image and a span on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I made 2 spans, one with a text and one with an image, but they aren't in the same line. Anyone has help?

HTML

```css
.übersicht{
    font-size: x-large;
    text-align: left;
}

.bild{
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<span class="überschrift">
    <h1>Übersicht</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>(Sir) Timothy John Berners-Lee</li>
        <li>Geboren am 8. Juni 1955 in London</li>
        <li>Britischer Physiker & Informatiker</li>
        <li>Begründer des World Wide Web</li>
        <li>Erfinder von HTML</li>
    </ul>
</span>
<span class="bild">
    <img src="bernerslee.png" alt="Dieses Bild ist nicht verfügbar." />
</span>
```

Comment: H1 and UL are not valid children of a SPAN

Comment: Use divs and flex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211079/show-two-div-in-same-line-in-same-horizontal-line-from-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your span inside div and add below css:

```css
.übersicht {
  font-size: x-large;
  text-align: left;
}

.bild {
  text-align: right;
}

.display-flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="display-flex">
  <span class="überschrift">
      <h1>Übersicht</h1>
      <ul>
          <li>(Sir) Timothy John Berners-Lee</li>
          <li>Geboren am 8. Juni 1955 in London</li>
          <li>Britischer Physiker & Informatiker</li>
          <li>Begründer des World Wide Web</li>
          <li>Erfinder von HTML</li>
      </ul>
  </span>
  <span class="bild">
      <img src="bernerslee.png" alt="Dieses Bild ist nicht verfügbar." />
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: There should not even BE  a span around the H1 and UL

Answer (score 0):

Just use float:right and float:left it will show like that

```css
.übersicht{
    font-size: x-large;
    float: left;
}

.bild{
    float: right;
   position:relative;
   bottom:110px;
}
```

```html
<span class="überschrift">
    <h1>Übersicht</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>(Sir) Timothy John Berners-Lee</li>
        <li>Geboren am 8. Juni 1955 in London</li>
        <li>Britischer Physiker & Informatiker</li>
        <li>Begründer des World Wide Web</li>
        <li>Erfinder von HTML</li>
    </ul>
</span>
<span class="bild">
    <img src="bernerslee.png" alt="Dieses Bild ist nicht verfügbar." />
</span>
```